# is displaymember needed?

Tags: c#, winforms

i got an enum

```
 public enum colorStatus
{
  green= 1,
  blue= 2,
  orange= 3,
}
```

When i bind it to the datagridviewcombobox, it works perfect.

```
  ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgSale.Columns["color"]).DataSource
           = Enum.GetValues(typeof(colorStatus));
```

**Questions:**
1) What is `DisplayMember and ValueMember` that i should set for that datagridviewcombobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't specify `DisplayMember`/`ValueMember`, the control uses `ToString` method to format the object, which gives a reasonable behavior for `enum`.

If you were displaying a more complex object, you could use `DisplayMember` to specify how should the object be displayed in the combobox (`ToString` doesn't always return useful information).

For example, if you had class with `Name` and `ID`, you could set `DisplayMember` to `Name` - the combo box would then display names of your objects. If you also set `ValueMember` to `ID` then you could use `SelectedValue` of the combobox to get the `ID` of the currently selected object.